# HTML - p tag inclusion within address tag

Tags: html

Are you allowed to include a `p` tag inside an `address` tag in HTML?

Comment: Could you please add an example code?

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `<p>` is classified as Flow Content and such is permitted within an `<address>` (There are some exceptions but `<p>` is not one)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/address

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it allowed if i understand you right

```
<address>
<p>Test</p>
Written by <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">Jon Doe</a>.<br> 
Visit us at:<br>
Example.com<br>
Box 564, Disneyland<br>
USA
</address>
```

Try here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_address

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add `p`, `span` tag inside `address` tag..if u include this tags, then in future, it will help you in styling contents..